# Text detection in table images

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ocr

I'm trying to extract the names from a table in an image as part of an OCR project.

For each image, I am trying to get bounding boxes around the name fields. I've managed to get bounding boxes on the names column but for some reason it's also detecting contours around the characters of the names inside each cell as well.

[image]

I have two questions:

1. Why are contours being detected around the characters, and how can I get them to appear around words instead?
2. Right now, I have to specify the location of the bounding boxes. How can I do this automatically?

Here's my code:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

file = r'Corrected_images\table_deskew3.png'
table_image_contour = cv2.imread(file, 0)
table_image = cv2.imread(file)

ret, thresh_value = cv2.threshold(table_image_contour, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
dilated_value = cv2.dilate(thresh_value, kernel, iterations=1)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated_value, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    # bounding the
    if 842 < x < 2215 and 1288 < y:
        table_image = cv2.rectangle(table_image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 3)
        roi = table_image[y: y + h, x: x + w]
        #plt.imshow(roi)
        #plt.show()
plt.imshow(table_image)
plt.show()
cv2.imwrite('target.png', table_image)
cv2.namedWindow('detectable', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
```

Comment: Contours are found for all white regions when you use RETR.TREE. That is it gets a hierarchy of contours within contours. So typically you need to ensure that the objects you want to find are white. Then, if they are not the outer (or external) contours, you need to filter them by some method, typically, area or perimeter, or dimensions or you can filter by hierarchy. Are you trying to get the text or the column and row lines? If the text, then you can try removing the long horizontal and vertical lines using morphology before extracting your contours.

Comment: @fmw42 I'm trying to get the entire column since all the cells are of the same size it would be better as I see it. Or I could possibly remove the table borders and lines then make the text (foreground) white and the background black and dialate the text so it would merge together sort off then apply bouding boxes, get their positions then crop them out on the original picture? does this seem like a better idea?

Comment: cell has bigger `area` then every single char - `area = width * height` - and you could use this to filter it. And there is `cv2.contourArea()` and `cv2.minAreaRect()`

Comment: Please post the original image that you are trying to process.

Comment: We can't debug your code if you do not provide your original unprocessed images!

Comment: Is getting the bounding will only be your final output?? if not then, I think you should follow the steps like, Convert Image to text (using lib like 'Tesseract), then use 'SpaCy' to identify the names and number (even you can do custom training of your own data), with this approach, you will able to get better-expected result.

Comment: You will always get contours for color differences. Is your aim to get the location of text below the column names in a fixed table format?

Comment: Here is an example that uses pytesseract: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66582628/18667225

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered making the image grayscale then passing a glow filter through it? That way the word merges into a solid entity.